# Conversion of ATL CString to character array

Tags: c++, visual-c++, char, c-strings

I want to convert a [`CString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa315043(v=vs.60).aspx) into a `char[]`. Some body tell me how to do this?

My code is like this :

```
CString strCamIP1 = _T("");
char g_acCameraip[16][17];
strCamIP1 = theApp.GetProfileString(strSection, _T("IP1"), NULL);
g_acCameraip[0] = strCamIP1;
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you 

I solved this with the help of WideCharToMultiByte method in the following way:

**TCHAR tchCamIPTemp[15];
 
_tcscpy(tchCamIPTemp, strCamIP1);
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, tchCamIPTemp, -1, g_acCameraip[0], sizeof(g_acCameraip[0]), NULL, NULL);**

Answer (score 9):

This seems to be along the right lines; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awkwbzyc.aspx

```
CString aCString = "A string";
char myString[256];
strcpy(myString, (LPCTSTR)aString);
```

which in your case would be along the lines of

```
strcpy(g_acCameraip[0], (LPCTSTR)strCamIP1);
```

Comment: I got an error as `error C2664: 'strcpy' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const unsigned short *' to 'const char *`

Comment: mistype: \CString aCString = "A string";
char myString[256];
strcpy(myString, (LPCTSTR)aString);

Comment: Imo this is the best and most simple way of doing it. If you wish to use C++ casts you can do `static_cast<LPCTSTR>(cstringVar)` and it will work under unicode and MBCS.

Comment: This fails on the 1st line: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "const char [9]" to "ATL::CStringT<wchar_t, StrTraitMFC<wchar_t, ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>>

Answer (score 7):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631.aspx) site:

```
// Convert to a char* string from CStringA string 
// and display the result.
CStringA origa("Hello, World!");
const size_t newsizea = (origa.GetLength() + 1);
char *nstringa = new char[newsizea];
strcpy_s(nstringa, newsizea, origa);
cout << nstringa << " (char *)" << endl;
```

CString is based on `TCHAR` so if don't compile with `_UNICODE` it's `CStringA` or if you do compile with `_UNICODE` then it is `CStringW`.

In case of `CStringW` conversion looks little bit different (example also from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631.aspx)):

```
// Convert to a char* string from a wide character 
// CStringW string. To be safe, we allocate two bytes for each
// character in the original string, including the terminating
// null.
const size_t newsizew = (origw.GetLength() + 1)*2;
char *nstringw = new char[newsizew];
size_t convertedCharsw = 0;
wcstombs_s(&convertedCharsw, nstringw, newsizew, origw, _TRUNCATE );
cout << nstringw << " (char *)" << endl;
```

Comment: would origw.GetLength() * 2 +1 be fine too?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [wcstombs_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7wzt4be.aspx):

```
// Convert CString to Char By Quintin Immelman.
//
CString DummyString;
// Size Can be anything, just adjust the 100 to suit. 
const size_t StringSize = 100;
// The number of characters in the string can be
// less than String Size. Null terminating character added at end.
size_t CharactersConverted = 0;

char DummyToChar[StringSize];

wcstombs_s(&CharactersConverted, DummyToChar, 
       DummyString.GetLength()+1, DummyString, 
       _TRUNCATE);
//Always Enter the length as 1 greater else 
//the last character is Truncated
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ATL you could use one of the conversion macros. CString stores data as tchar, so you would use CT2A() (C in macro name stands for const):

```
CString from("text");

char* pStr = CT2A((LPCTSTR)from);
```

Those macros are smart, if tchar represents ascii (no _UNICODE defined), they just pass the pointer over and do nothing.

More info below, under **ATL String-Conversion Classes** section:
http://www.369o.com/data/books/atl/index.html?page=0321159624%2Fch05.html

Comment: I like this: `CString from("text"); CT2A pStr(from);`

Answer (score 0):

`CStringA/W` is cheaply and implicitly convertible to `const char/wchar_t *`. Whenever you need C-style string, just pass `CString` object itself (or the result of `.GetString()` which is the same). The pointer will stay valid as long as string object is alive and unmodified.

```
strcpy(g_acCameraip[0], strCamIP1);
// OR
strcpy(g_acCameraip[0], strCamIP1.GetString());
```

If you need writable (non-const) buffer, use `.GetBuffer()` with optional maximum length argument.

If you have `CStringW` but you need `const char*` and vice versa, you can use a temporary `CStringA` object:

```
strcpy(g_acCameraip[0], CStringA(strCamIP1).GetString());
```

---

But a much better way would be to have array of `CString`s. You can use them whereever you need null-terminated string, but they will also manage string's memory for you.

```
std::vector<CString> g_acCameraip(16);
g_acCameraip[0] = theApp.GetProfileString(strSection, _T("IP1"), NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use memcpy .

```
char c [25];
Cstring cstr = "123";
memcpy(c,cstr,cstr.GetLength());
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you **really** have to **copy** the `CString` objects into fixed `char` arrays?

```
enum { COUNT=16 };
CString Cameraip[COUNT];
Cameraip[0] = theApp.GetProfileString(strSection, _T("IP1"), NULL);
// add more entries...
```

...and then - later - when accessing the entries, for example like this

```
for (int i=0; i<COUNT; ++i) {
    someOp(Cameraip[i]); // the someOp function takes const CString&
}
```

...you may [convert them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms235631.aspx), *if* needed.

Answer (score 0):

fopen is the function which needs char* param. so if you have CString as available string, you can just use bellow code.
be happy :)
Here, `cFDlg.GetPathName().GetString();` basically returns CString in my code.

```
char*pp  = (char*)cFDlg.GetPathName().GetString();
FILE *fp = ::fopen(pp,"w");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    CString str;
    //Do something
    char* pGTA = (LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)str;//Now the cast
```

Just (LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR). Hope this is what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

```
char strPass[256];
strcpy_s( strPass, CStringA(strCommand).GetString() );
```

Answer (score 0):

### It's simple

[ATL CStrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa315043(v=vs.60).aspx) allow very simple usage without having to do a lot of conversions between types. You can most easily do:

```
CString cs = "Test";
const char* str = static_cast<LPCTSTR>(cs);
```

or in UNICODE environment:

```
CString cs = "Test";
const wchar_t* str = static_cast<LPCTSTR>(cs);
```

### How it works

The [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) (or alternatively C-Style cast) will trigger the [`CString::operator LPCTSTR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300569(v=vs.60).aspx), so you don't do any pointer reinterpretation yourself but rely on ATL code!

The documentation of this cast operator says:

> This useful casting operator provides an efficient method to **access the null-terminated C string** contained in a **CString** object. ***No characters are copied; only a pointer is returned.*** Be careful with this operator. If you change a **CString** object after you have obtained the character pointer, you may cause a reallocation of memory that invalidates the pointer.

### Modifiable Pointers

As mentioned in the above statement, the returned pointer by the cast operator is **not meant to be modified**. However, if you still need to use a modifiable pointer for some outdated C libraries, you can use a [`const_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) (if you are sure that function wont modify the pointer):

```
void Func(char* str) // or wchar_t* in Unicode environment
{
    // your code here
}

// In your calling code:
CString cs = "Test";
Func(const_cast<LPTSTR>(static_cast<LPCTSTR>(test))); // Call your function with a modifiable pointer
```

If you wish to modify the pointer, you wont get around doing some kind of memory copying to modifiable memory, as mentioned by other answers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hardcoded method..

```html
CString a = L"This is CString!";
char *dest = (char *)malloc(a.GetLength() + 1);
// +1 because of NULL char

dest[a.GetLength()] = 0; // setting null char

char *q = (char *)a.m_pszData;
//Here we cannot access the private member..
//The address of "m_pszData" private member is stored in first DWORD of &a...
//Therefore..

int address = *((int *)&a);

char *q = (char *)address;
// Now we can access the private data!, This is the real magic of C
// Size of CString's characters is 16bit...
// in cstring '1' will be stored as 0x31 0x00 (Hex)
// Here we just want even indexed chars..

for(int i = 0;i<(a.GetLength()*2);i += 2)
  dest[i/2] = *(q+i);

// Now we can use it..
printf("%s", dest);
```