# cannot convert argument 1 from 'ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,ATL::StrTraitATL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>>' to 'const char *'

Tags: c++, mfc, atl, cstring

How to convert this way properly?

```
    VARIANT varIndex;
    CString csIndex;
    //Index BSTR
    csIndex = (LPCSTR)(_bstr_t)vtIndex;
    csIndex.MakeUpper();
    if (csIndex.Left(3) == PROCESSUS_TABLE)
    {
        lIndex = atoi((LPCSTR)csIndex.Mid(3));
        if ((unsigned long)lIndex<0)
            return E_INVALIDARG;
    }
```

Error message:

```
C2664: 'int atoi(const char *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,ATL::StrTraitATL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>>' to 'const char *'
```

I couldn't find how to fix this, any good idea, please?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10578592/1938163

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable 'csIndex' is a unicoce string(`wchar_t`), while the macro LPCSTR is for the ansi string (`char`).

So you should use Unicode functions, the code will be:

```
lIndex = _wtoi((LPCWSTR)csIndex.Mid(3));
```

There's no problem with this line:

```
csIndex = (LPCSTR)(_bstr_t)vtIndex;
```

It is because that the smart pointer type _bstr_t can handle char*/wchar_t* conversion automatically.

Comment: error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'ATL::CStringT<BaseType,StringTraits>' to 'LPCWSTR'

Answer (score 1):

`CComVariant::ChangeType` makes it available to you through `.bstrVal` member, [`_ttoi`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd5xkb5c.aspx) instead of `atoi`:

```
VARIANT vtIndex;
// ...
CComVariant vStringIndex;
HRESULT nResult = vStringIndex.ChangeType(VT_BSTR, &vtIndex);
if(FAILED(nResult))
  ; // TODO: Handle error
CString csIndex(vStringIndex.bstrVal);
csIndex.MakeUpper();
if (csIndex.Left(3) == PROCESSUS_TABLE)
{
    lIndex = _ttoi(csIndex.Mid(3));
    // ...
```